# Cannot extract item from a list in cmake

Tags: list, cmake

I cannot extract an item from a list. The following code replicates my issue:

```
set(TEST_LIST "aaa" "bbb" "ccc")
list(GET ${TEST_LIST} 1 TEST_ITEM)
message("TEST_ITEM = ${TEST_ITEM}")   # Expect: bbb
```

What I get is:

```
TEST_ITEM = NOTFOUND
```

The index 1 should point to the second element `bbb`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @squareskittles - Yes, it does. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works without braces and dollars:

```
list(GET TEST_LIST 1 TEST_ITEM)
```